# Enterprise Program having limits in app installations?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, enterprise, ad-hoc-distribution

My organisation is planning to buy Enterprise program from Apple. We have a doubt regarding max number of installation for application.

Inside apple website they have define some installation values like this:

1. Apple Watch 100 per year
2. iPhone 100 per year
3. iPad 100 per year
4. iPod touch 100 per year

Does these means we are limited to 100 installation totally in each devices for all our Apps i.e., 400 total installation possible for multiple apps.

Can someone explain in detail?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enterprise program does not have those limitations.  Those are limitations for registered devices on a standard Apple developer account.  On an enterprise account, you don't need to register devices before you can install your self developed apps on them.  The device user needs to "trust" your developer profile, but that's it.

No limitation on devices that I am aware of - as there are companies using this type of developer account / enterprise distribution profile to distribute apps to thousands of employees.

I think the main limitation is that you should only use it for distributing your app to employees or contractors that should have access.  In other words, don't try to use it to set up your own app store distributing custom apps to random people.  Also, the enterprise distribution profiles expire after a year, so there is ongoing maintenance to keep the apps running on devices.

Comment: Do we need to pass our certificate to all the user to run on their devices?

Comment: No, the enterprise in house distribution profile will be packaged with the app when you build and will be installed on the device when they install the app.  The cert is used on the build machine to sign the app. The developer(s) building the app will need to install the cert on their Macs.  The first time they install an app that uses your enterprise profile, they will need to trust the enterprise profile by going to Settings->General->Profiles & Device Management. You should see your company under the Enterprise Apps section. Users will select your company, then click the "Trust" button.

Comment: Thanks @wottle this answer is more helpful for us to go forward to take Enterprise account.